# On duplicate key update error

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I used the function ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. It's weird because on my other codes, it works just fine, but with this one, I can still get records that are the same.

Here's my stored proc.

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(playlist_id) FROM playlists WHERE playlist_id = i_playlistid) > 0)  THEN

   INSERT INTO playlist_terminal (playlist_id,terminal_id,userid,booking_id) VALUES        (i_playlistid,i_terminal_id,i_userid,i_booking_id)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE terminal_id = i_terminal_id;

   SELECT terminal.terminal_id,terminal.plate_number,terminal.terminal_status,
   terminal.location, terminal_sum.booking_id FROM terminal
   INNER JOIN playlist_terminal
   ON terminal.terminal_id = playlist_terminal.terminal_id
   INNER JOIN terminal_sum
   ON playlist_terminal.terminal_id = terminal_sum.terminal_id
   WHERE playlist_terminal.userid = i_userid AND playlist_id = i_playlistid;
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a `UNIQUE` key in place for any of the column in your `INSERT` column list. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` only works when the `INSERT` would create a duplicate entry for a `UNIQUE` key. What's your `CREATE TABLE` statement for `playlist_terminal`?

Comment: Is it only allowed if the one I am using is the primary key? Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Is it only allowed if the one I am using is the primary key."  If you attempt to do an INSERT that would cause a duplicate entry for a UNIQUE (which includes PRIMARY) key, the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause will be used.  If not, it will be ignored.

Comment: The one i am using for on duplicate key update is not a primary key.

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  This logic won't work.  Either include in your INSERT a column (or the set of columns) corresponding to a unique key or come up with different logic for identifying the rows to update.